# Multiple MySQL/PHP Queries on one page, not playing fair!

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following MySQL Query:

```
<div class="box" id="settlement1">
        <?
            $query  = "SELECT name, pub, hospital, trade FROM settlements WHERE settlementID = 1";
            $result = mysql_query($query);

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $settlementName = $row['name'];
                $pubExists = $row['pub'];
                $hospitalExists = $row['hospital'];
                $tradeExists = $row['trade'];
            }
        ?>
        <div class="settlement-name"><? echo $settlementName; ?></div>
        <div class="settlement-contents">
            <?
                if ($hospitalExists == '1') { echo "<div class='hospital'>HOSPITAL</div>";  }
                if ($pubExists == '1') { echo "<div class='pub'>PUB</div>"; }
                if ($tradeExists == '1') { echo "<div class='trade'>TRADE</div>"; }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="settlement2">
        <?
            $query  = "SELECT name, shop, hospital, trade FROM settlements WHERE settlementID = 2";
            $result = mysql_query($query);

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $settlementName = $row['name'];
                $pubExists = $row['pub'];
                $hospitalExists = $row['hospital'];
                $tradeExists = $row['trade'];
            }
        ?>
        <div class="settlement-name"><? echo $settlementName; ?></div>
        <div class="settlement-contents">
            <?
                if ($hospitalExists == '1') { echo "<div class='hospital'>HOSPITAL</div>";  }
                if ($pubExists == '1') { echo "<div class='pub'>PUB</div>"; }
                if ($tradeExists == '1') { echo "<div class='trade'>TRADE</div>"; }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now, the first query works fine, but the second returns the same results as the first.

***ALL FIELDS ARE DIFFERENT IN QUERY 1 TO QUERY 2***

^_^ <( HELP! )

Comment: Have you checked if you don't have same values for those two settlementID values?

Comment: You should probably post the entire snippet from the point you have already posted to the point where you get the wrong DB resutls.

Comment: Updated answer to include more info

Comment: Why do you basically copy paste the same operation twice? Collapse it into one function and then see if you still have the problem. However, the only error I see is you use $row['pub'] and not $row['shop'] in the second case.

Comment: @Fletcher Moore - Woot! Cheers, I didn't see that "pub"!! If you answer quick enough, you can have the points ;)

Comment: Fair's fair :) Sorry FletcherMoore - I'll vote something else of yours up :)

Comment: BTW, this is why copy-paste is bad!

Comment: Excellent answer - that's how SO **should** be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the cause but...

first SQL:

```
$query  = "SELECT name, pub, hospital, trade FROM settlements WHERE settlementID = 1";
```

Second:

```
$query  = "SELECT name, shop, hospital, trade FROM settlements WHERE settlementID = 2";
```

in first one there's pub, in second one - shop. But you don't use shop value in PHP in second case, only pub (which is not in this SQL fields.

You may have SQL error here (no field in database) or PHP error (checking non-existent field in result array).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you reuse the variable **$query** or **$result** further down leading to output the result of the first $query or to execute the same query again?

Comment: Can I not use the same variable? I tried doing `$query = NULL` and `$result = NULL` and this made no difference...

Comment: Do you buy your variables, so that you only have limited variables qty ? ;). Try with other variables, just to see if it works.

Comment: Of course you can use same variables, but it's often a problem that one doesn't assign new value to the variable (by mistake). Now, when you sent us more code, it looks that it's not your case.

Comment: right, that is what i am talking about. one can reuse variables, but it is a possible source of errors